# Linear independency at set of matrices.

Tags: matrices

[For example this matrix set here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO0EF.png)

$$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, A_2=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, A_3=\begin{bmatrix}3&6\\0&4\end{bmatrix}$$

How can I determine this set of matrices are linearly independent or not? Like I know how to calculate linear independence on sets like:
$$v_1=(2, −1, 5) \ v_2=(1, 3, −4) \ v_3=(−3, −9, 12)$$ but I dont know how to do that thing on matrices.

thank you.

Comment: thanks for the edit alain.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. I took the liberty to write the matrix for you. It is better to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of picture, it is easier to search.

Comment: Welcome. $\begin{bmatrix}3&6\\0&4\end{bmatrix}$, it's just like $(3,6,0,4)$.

Comment: thank you a lot dudes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you have to treat the matrices as vectors. So, set up the equation $$c_1A_1+c_2A_2+c_3A_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
To get
$$\begin{bmatrix}c_1+2c_2+3c_3 &c_1-c_2+6c_3\\0&c_1+c_2+4c_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$